# JButton toggle disable and enable ItemListener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm trying to make a button that will enable or disable another button. I'm not sure why it's not entering the ItemListener or is ItemListener only used for toggle events? Here's my code.

This is in the main method:

```
        resumePause = new JButton ("Pause/Resume") ;
        leftPanel.add(resumePause) ;
        deleteObj = new JButton ("Delete");
        leftPanel.add(deleteObj);

        //sets delete button to disabled and resume to enable
        resumePause.setEnabled(true);
        deleteObj.setEnabled(false);
        // register the frame as a listener for Item events 
        resumePause.addItemListener(this);
```

This is the ItemEvent method:

```
public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent e) {
        System.out.println("In ItemStateChanged");
        if (playPause.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println("Delete enabled");
            deleteObj.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Delete disabled");
            deleteObj.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

I added those println() to check if it ever enters `itemStateChanged` but it never does.

Comment: JButton's don't use ItemListener's they use ActionListener's

Comment: Ok, thought I could use it with ItemListener but I'll change it to ActionListener instead. What would be the equivalent action listener's method to `setEnable` `isSelected` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a JToggleButton and then use the original listener, an ItemListener on it.

Comment: Perfect, that was the easier and simpler fix. thanks!